# How to structure the angular application

Tags: angular, architecture

I have to structure and design the plan of the Components and modules of the angular application.

Please follow the screenshot provided with the detail.

1. The entry page to the application is the **Landing Page**, Where we have 3 different Buttons [ B1, B2, B3 ].
2. When clicking on the Buttons on the Landing Page, User lands to three different pages, ( Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 corresponding to the Buttons )
3. From Page 1 to Page 4, Page 4 consists of some of the common components which can be used across multiple pages, these components can Toolbar, Product Heading, Buttons bar.
4. On Click of Button B4 on Page 4, User lands to Page 5.
5. On Page 5, we have Common Components which are common inside succeeding Pages 6 , 7 , 8.
6. From Page 5 we have a Component which has a segment of Screens [S1, S2, S3, S4 ]
7. On Clicking on S1 to S4 the layout will be same and only the content will be changed.

How to create structure and modularize this application on angular ?

Below I am sharing my knowledge:

**Components :**

- Landing Page
- Root

  - Toolbar ( child component )
  - Product Heading ( child Component )
  - Button Bar ( child Component )
  - Segment Bar ( Only visible from Page 5 )
- Shared Module

  - Toolbar
  - Product Heading
  - Button Bar
  - Segment Bar
- Services Module

  - services

[image: High Level flow of the application]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion will be do like this.

```
src
 -pages
  --Landing Page
  --page1
  --page2
  --page3

 -services
  --service

 -components
  --toolbar
  --product heading
  --button bar
  --segment bar
```

you can refactor pages also as per requirements.
e.g. if mainly all components are common on these pages. you can refactor all those common components into separate component then you can include that component in your pages.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Hi Piyush! What about the root Component ? and its Child component ?

Comment: app component will be root component where you will use router outlet.
Each page will be a module so that you can use lazy loading .
all component s you can keep in components folder. e.g. in components you have a, b, c, d, e components. Not on page 1 you wanna use a, b only and page 2 d, e only and on page 2 b, c.

you can simply add components in respective pages.

Comment: inside src folder you can create folder for directives also and pipes also.

Comment: Thanks Piyush that helps well enough to some extent.

Comment: if you have any doubt.. let me know. Will be happy to help.